# Getting information with laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I having 3 model, User, Profile, University
i set up the relationship with

User model

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Profile model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In profile table it will contain `university_id` & `user_id`column as foreign key.

In University model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now i want to get data with `$discussion->user->profile->university->name` but it return `Trying to get property of non-object` .
What is the problems?

Comment: $discussion = ....should it be that way?

Comment: You want to get university name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Profile model add;

```
public function university(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\University');
}
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

In university model add;

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Profile');
}
```

then you can call;

```
$discussion->profile->university->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make a relationship with profile model and university model

**Profile model**

```
Public function university  () {
    return $this->belongsTo ('App\University')
}
```

**University model**

```
Public function profile  () {
    return $this->belongsTo ('App\Profile')
}
```

Now try :

```
$discussion->user->profile->university->name
```

Comment: you are basically saying that each university has one profile(student)